# Where should Avro GenericData Record be converted to CustomEvent which implements Avro SpecificRecord?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, avro, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

Using `spring-boot 2.4.4, spring-kafka 2.6.7, kafka client 2.6.0, confluent 6.6.1` (for `KafkaAvroSerializer` & schema registry), `Scala 13`.

```
CustomEvent implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {}

@KafkaListener(topics = "..", containerFactory = "..", errorHandler = "..")
public void processStreamMessage(@Payload CustomEvent customEvent, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {}
```

In "production", the `@KafkaListener` gets called with proper `CustomEvent` `@Payload`, so somewhere this conversion happens from bytes, to `Avro GenericRecord` and then to `CustomEvent SpecificRecord`.

But in component tests, depending where we run them (gradle locally / gradle in docker) it either goes green or it fails with `"Cannot convert from [org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record] to CustomEvent"`...it is even stranger, in the sense that component tests pass on mac but not in docker but when trying to debug always hit `Cannot convert from [org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record] to..CustomEvent..`

I checked that a single version of any jar exists in the boot jar. So non determinism from dependencies seems excluded. Not sure what else could make the difference between where it works (deployment; gradle test run locally on mac) and where it fails (gradle test in docker).

Where should this conversion happen?

Answer (score 1):

The conversion is done by the `KafkaAvroDeserializer`; you need to set its `specific.avro.reader` property to true.

`KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG`.

My guess is this is true in production but somehow not in your tests.

Show your configuration and tests.